Failed to resolve host network app id Warning: -[BETextInput attributedMarkedText] is unimplemented
friends! We really need your help!! I am creating a mobile application using Ioinic Capacitor (v6) for iOS and android. The application is essentially a link to a third-party website that opens using WebView. Everything works fine on Android. But when running on the simulator, an error occurs in Xcode:

Failed to resolve host network app id
Warning: -[BETextInput attributedMarkedText] is unimplemented
⚡️  Loading app at capacitor://localhost...
⚡️  WebView loaded
SplashScreen.hideSplash: SplashScreen was automatically hidden after default timeout. You should call SplashScreen.hide() as soon as your web app is loaded (or increase the timeout). Read more at https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/splash-screen#hiding-the-splash-screen

The iOS app starts, a Splash Screen appears, which disappears after 2 seconds and then a blank screen...
At the moment, there is no longer access to Apple devices and Xcode. Therefore, I build the application in Ionic Appflow, and test runs in the app time.io Therefore, unfortunately, I will not be able to throw off more detailed logs ... Maybe someone has encountered something similar, I will be grateful for any help. Here are some files to understand:
package.json
{
  "name": "capacitor-app",
  "version": "2408.0.24",
  "description": "An Amazing Capacitor App",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [
    "capacitor",
    "mobile"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^6.1.2",
    "@capacitor/camera": "latest",
    "@capacitor/core": "^6.1.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^6.1.2",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/assets": "^3.0.5",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^6.1.2",
    "vite": "^2.9.13"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

capacitor.config.json
{
  "appId": "test.ios.app",
  "appName": "App",
  "webDir": "dist",
  "version": "2408.0.24",
  "server": {
    "iosScheme": "https"
  },
  "ios": {
    "build": {
      "developmentTeam": ""
    }
  },
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 2000,
      "launchAutoHide": true,
      "launchFadeOutDuration": 2000,
      "androidScaleType": "FIT_XY",
      "backgroundColor": "#1F2131",
      "splashBackgroundColor": "#121617",
      "splashBackgroundColorDark": "#121617",
      "androidSplashResourceName": "splash",
      "androidSplashDarkResourceName": "splash",
      "showSpinner": false,
      "splashFullScreen": true,
      "splashImmersive": true,
      "layoutName": "launch_screen",
      "useDialog": true
    }
  }
}

AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import Capacitor

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return ApplicationDelegateProxy.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        return ApplicationDelegateProxy.shared.application(application, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
    }
}

Main.storyboard
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14111" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Bridge View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="CAPBridgeViewController" customModule="Capacitor" sceneMemberID="viewController"/>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>

LaunchScreen.storyboard
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17132" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17105"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <imageView key="view" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="Splash" id="snD-IY-ifK">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                    </imageView>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="53" y="375"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="Splash" width="1366" height="1366"/>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>

Info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>IQL</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

Splash Screen.hide() also does not work in index.js (in the main index.html ), unfortunately I can't upload detailed logs...
registerPlugin("CapacitorHttp", {
  web: () => new CapacitorHttpPluginWeb()
});
const SplashScreen = registerPlugin("SplashScreen", {
  web: () => __vitePreload(() => import("./web.af70e0c8.js"), true ? [] : void 0).then((m) => new m.SplashScreenWeb())
});
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  console.log("load app");
  SplashScreen.hide();
});

Capacitor uses the CAPBridgeViewController class (Main.storyboard). I tried to write my own class to handle the display of MyViewController, but it cannot be found by AppDelegate (cannot find 'MyViewController' in scope) if I import MyViewController in AppDelegate (no such module 'MyViewController'):
MyViewController.swift
import UIKit
import WebKit
import Capacitor


class MyViewController: CAPBridgeViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://iql.finance/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}

updated AppDelegate
import UIKit
import Capacitor

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let viewController = MyViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {}

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {}

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {}

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return ApplicationDelegateProxy.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        return ApplicationDelegateProxy.shared.application(application, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
    }
}

and changing the CustomClass in the Main.storyboard
<viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="MyViewController" customModule="Capacitor" sceneMemberID="viewController"/>

What could be the problem, maybe someone has encountered it? Thank you so much in advance for any help

Hi! I’ve been seeing similar errors following updates to MacOS, Xcode and / or iOS.
Errors:
nw_application_id_create_self NECP_CLIENT_ACTION_GET_SIGNED_CLIENT_ID [80: Authentication error]
Failed to resolve host network app id
Warning: -[BETextInput attributedMarkedText] is unimplemented
Invalidating grant <invalid NS/CF object> failed

Could any of you resolve this?
